# How to provide TypeScript annotation to existing global function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm considering adding TypeScript type annotations to an existing project.
I'm having trouble providing an external declaration file for a very simple example:

**program.ts**:

```
/// <reference path="types.d.ts"/>

function greet (p) {
    console.log(p.name);
}

var x = {name: 'Mary'};

greet(x);
```

**types.d.ts**:

```
interface Person {
    height?: number,
    name: string
}

declare function greet (p: Person): void;
```

I expected this to work but I'm getting the following error:

`program.ts(3,10): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.`

It seems to think that the function definition is an overload and not the implementation of a previous declaration.

What is the right way to add a type to the `greet` function?

**Requirement:** the `program.ts` should be plain JavaScript, e.g., free from any type annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported or allowed by the language. Essentially the code is doing...

```
interface Person {
    height?: number,
    name: string
}

declare function greet(p: Person): void;

function greet(p: any): void {
    console.log(p.name);
}
```

So you get that error for defining a function and ambient function with the same name.

> What is the right way to add a type to the greet function?

It's to do this:

```
interface Person {
    height?: number,
    name: string
}

function greet(p: Person): void {
    console.log(p.name);
}
```

> Requirement: the program.ts should be plain JavaScript, e.g., free from any type annotations.

This isn't possible without changing the code in *program.ts*. One possibility is to change *program.ts* to *program.js* then describe *program.js* with a declaration file for use in other files. That would only mean other files using *program.js* could benefit from knowing the type and structure of that file, but it wouldn't stop you from making mistakes in *program.js*.

Note that the main purpose of definition files is to provide type information for code found in `.js` files—not `.ts` files.

Comment: Describing `program.js` without changing the extension to `.ts` does sound like the right thing to do, given that I'm trying to extend an existing code base. Too bad there's no full type safety then. Anyway, great answer!